# Test android opengl es 2.0 without physical handset , is there any way?

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

Can i test opengl es 2.0 (im using ndk ) without using  physical handset plugged into the pc?
i know the emulator doesn't support es 2 only 1 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are some OpenGL ES 2.0 (e.g. [Mali](http://www.malideveloper.com/developer-resources/tools/opengl-es-20-emulator.php)) emulators out there, so if you are looking to test your OpenGL code, it should be just a matter of creating JNI binding for the emulator, and running the code as a Java app.

If you're looking to debug the application as a whole, then the answer could very well be no.

Comment: Correct, there's also the powervr sdk. I use it that in combination with a small application wrapper to test my c++ and opengl es code.

Comment: That's right. We used PowerVR emulator as well, but then we had some problems with it and switched over to Mali. Not sure what the problem was, though.